# Error while trying to read files from Helidon MP

Tags: java, rest, file, helidon

I am new to Helidon MP and i am getting an error while trying to write logic for file reading, below are the details for the same :

### Compilation Error :

The type io.helidon.media.common.MessageBodyReadableContent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

### Code/Logic

```
@Path("/list/upload")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void uploadHeaders(ServerRequest req, ServerResponse res) {
        
        
        req.content().as(MultiPart.class).thenAccept(multiPart -> {
            for(BodyPart bodyPart : multiPart.bodyParts()){
                String content = bodyPart.as(String.class);
                System.out.println("Part:\n" + content);
            }
        });
    }
```

### Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

    Copyright (c) 2018, 2019 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at

        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.

-->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>codes.recursive</groupId>
    <artifactId>telenet-helidon-mp-poc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <properties>
        <helidon.version>1.1.1</helidon.version>
        <mainClass>codes.recursive.cnms.user.Main</mainClass>
        <exec.mainClass>${mainClass}</exec.mainClass>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
        <libs.classpath.prefix>libs</libs.classpath.prefix>
        <copied.libs.dir>${project.build.directory}/${libs.classpath.prefix}</copied.libs.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
        <checkstyle.config.location>etc/checkstyle.xml</checkstyle.config.location>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.6</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>${libs.classpath.prefix}</classpathPrefix>
                                <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                                <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.jboss.jandex
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            jandex-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.0.6,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>jandex</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${copied.libs.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <excludeScope>test</excludeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-index</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jandex</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.helidon</groupId>
                <artifactId>helidon-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${helidon.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
                <version>2.26</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.helidon.microprofile.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>helidon-microprofile-1.2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>
    <version>18.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>osdt_core</artifactId>
    <version>18.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>osdt_cert</artifactId>
    <version>18.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.media/helidon-media-multipart -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.webserver/helidon-webserver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.webserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-webserver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.media/helidon-media-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-media-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.common/helidon-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.webclient/helidon-webclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.webclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-webclient</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.webserver/helidon-webserver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.webserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-webserver</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.media/helidon-media-project -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-media-project</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.media.jackson/helidon-media-jackson-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.media.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-media-jackson-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The code you have excerpted is not Helidon MP.  Did you mean Helidon SE?

Comment: I am trying to do file read using Helidon MP, i just got this piece of code from Git hub, so assumed it should be Helidon MP. If possible can you guide me to the correct code/blog to Read/Write File from Helidon MP.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the *Helidon* BOM (aka. *Bill-of-Material*), you shouldn't be declaring explicit versions for sub-modules (`helidon-media-xxx` in this case) otherwise you will fall into incompatibility issues, as the one you are facing.

In your `dependencyManagement` section, you declared `helidon-bom` as a POM import:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.helidon</groupId>
            <artifactId>helidon-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${helidon.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Other dependencies -->
</dependencyManagement>
```

The `helidon.version` should be the only version declared for all `helidon-xxx` artifacts (note that concrete artifacts versions could be different under the hood but that would be managed within the BOM itself and you should not play with that).

Here what the dependencies section would look like with all `helidon-xxx` artifacts versions omitted:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.helidon.microprofile.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>helidon-microprofile-1.2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>19.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>
        <version>18.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>osdt_core</artifactId>
        <version>18.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>osdt_cert</artifactId>
        <version>18.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.helidon.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>helidon-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.helidon.webserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>helidon-webserver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.helidon.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>helidon-media-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.helidon.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>helidon-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.helidon.webclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>helidon-webclient</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.helidon.webserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>helidon-webserver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.helidon.media.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>helidon-media-jackson-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```